# I'm not able to add GitHub to my computer’s list of acceptable SSH hosts

Tags: github, ssh, terminal, ssh-keys, github-for-mac

I have a Macbook, macOS Monterey Version 12.0.1
I generated the key id_rsa and enter the passcode and even added the key to my GitHub account  but when I try to add GitHub to my computer's list of acceptable SSH hosts using ssh –T git@github.com

this message keeps showing up...

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ?\200\223t: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I tried to change my DNS to Open DNS 208.67.222.222, but this didn't fix the issue. I'm a complete beginner so I don't know if I'm missing something.

Comment: It's probably the "–" before the `T` – that's endash. Use just a simple hyphen/minus sign "-": `-T`

Comment: Thank you so much I can't believe it was so simple I just copy and pasted it from the instructions I was given lol.